# What is the use of jobs other than bootstrap jobs and scheduled jobs?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I know that jobs are useful to run a method in the start of the application (Bootstrap Job) and to run a method in a periodic interval of method (Scheduled Job).

But is there any other use of Jobs?

I mean, if I want to update the data in a database. In that case, do I want to write the code as a Job? If so, why are we doing that?

Please guide me on this.

I am using Play 1.2.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several uses of the jobs in play. They are well explained in the official [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/jobs). I'll summarize the documentation with example usages.

- **Bootstrapping Jobs**

  - Initializing the application state, such as initial `database data insert`, `loading Spring context` etc.
- **Scheduled Jobs**

  - Scheduled periodical tasks, such as `batch db processing`, `report generation`, `daily reports` etc.
- **Long running tasks (Triggering task jobs)**

  - If you have a *long running task*, and you *don't want to block the request* i.e. you want to return response, even though the task is not finish, then this is appropriate case for using jobs.

    - In this cases, the jobs are most commonly combined with reverse ajax (Comet), in order to track the status of the job (good example is given [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/asynchronous)).
    - Other example is `data importing with progress status`. In this case, you should use class for persisting the progress status.
- **Shutdown Jobs**

  - An example here is `persisting the cache data`, or other in-memory data, `releasing some used resources` etc.

In a regular database insert, I don't recommend using Job, since you should implement complicated techniques in order to obtain the result. As I mentioned earlier, if this task is *very slow* and you want to *return the response faster*, you can use a Job. Also, when you *don't want to return the status* of the database action (which is bad practice), and want to return the response faster, you can use Job. However, take care that the jobs are asynchronous and *you must resolve the possible concurrency issues*.

There are many more usages of the Jobs in Play (and in general) and it is impossible to cover them all, but I hope that this response will help you.